# open a new window on page load and be active

Tags: asp.net, popupwindow

I was trying to open a new pop up window on page load and the new window was successfully opened but the new window was opened behind the page of the main page. I would like to have the new window to b active in front of the main page. The code is in code-behind and as below:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript(me.GetType(),"popup","<script language=javascript>window.open('WebForm2.aspx','','width=300px,height=200px')</script>")
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `.focus()` at the end of `window.open`:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript(me.GetType(),"popup","<script language=javascript>window.open('WebForm2.aspx','','width=300px,height=200px').focus();</script>")
End If
```

If that doesn't work - something else in the main page is taking over. You can try placing open/focus in `setTimeout` block (by the way, you don't have to add script tags yourself, just pass last parameter to `RegisterStartupScript` as `True`:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript(me.GetType(),"popup","setTimeout(""window.open('WebForm2.aspx','','width=300px,height=200px').focus();"",1);", True)
End If
```

Comment: The popup still opens behind the main page? If so - do you have any additional 3rd party ASP.NET controls on the main page?

Comment: yes, it's still behind the main page and I do have some AJAX control toolkit controls on the main page.

Comment: I have added another version, can u give it a try?